# How to insert a string into an ArrayList in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I am working in VB.net to help teach myself the language. The program I am creating requires the input of two strings, both of which I would like to add to an ArrayList in a specific way.

For the first input, say `Hello World`, I would like to capitalize the letters and input it into a list of the form:

`InputCharacterList = {"H","E","L","L","O"," ","W","O","R","L","D"}`

After this I would then like to convert this into an ArrayList of Integers using the characters ASCII values, so:

`IntegerList = {72,69,76,76,79,32,87,79,82,76,68}`

**Note:** I want to capitalize all the letters because I want to guarantee that my IntegerList contains only integers with 2 numbers.

Now for the next part, I pretty much want to do the reverse. So if the input is a string: `7269767679`, I want to create an ArrayList of Integers such as:

`InputIntegerList = {72,69,76,76,79}`

I then want to convert it back into an ArrayList using ASCII values, so:

`CharacterList = {"H","E","L","L","O"}`

This second way seems to be much more difficult to me. I cannot easily see how to step through a string two values at a time. Nevertheless I cannot easily see how to do either approach in VB.net

Thanks for the help!

Comment: String.SubString() method is what you're looking for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_

Comment: You just need a loop from `0` to `"7269767679".Length - 1`, Step 2. Then SubString() it taking two chars from the current position of the iterator and parse the value with `Integer.Parse()`. Why are you talking about `ArrayLists`? Use `List(Of String)` and `List(Of Integer)`

Comment: To second what Jimi said, `ArrayList` has been obsolete since the introduction of generics in .NET 2.0.  Use the appropriate `List(Of T)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim sInput As String = "Hello World"
    Dim sOutput As String
    Dim AL_c As New ArrayList
    Dim AL_b As New ArrayList

    ' Add Input to Arraylist
    AL_c.AddRange(sInput.ToUpper.ToArray)

    ' Add Bytes to Arralist
    For Each c As Char In AL_c
        AL_b.Add(Convert.ToByte(c))
    Next

    sOutput = String.Concat(AL_b.ToArray)

    ' Reverse
    sInput = "7269767679"

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cTemp As Char

    AL_c.Clear()
    AL_b.Clear()
    i = sInput.Length

    ' Add Bytes to Arraylist
    For Each c As Char In sInput.ToArray
        If (i And 1) = 0 Then
            cTemp = c
        Else
            AL_b.Add(CByte(cTemp & c))
        End If
        i -= 1
    Next

    ' Add Characters to Arraylist
    For Each b As Byte In AL_b
        AL_c.Add(Chr(b))
    Next

    ' Create Output string = "HELLO"
    sOutput = String.Concat(AL_c.ToArray)
```